# Render link attribute in custom page builder content type

Tags: uicomponent, widget, page-builder

Lets assume a custom page builder content type with a text attribute representing a link

In `master.html` I'm already retrieving the following attributes

```
<!--master.html-->
<<div attr="data.main.attributes"
     ko-style="data.main.style"
     css="data.main.css"
>
    <div class="homebanner-content">
        <h3 attr="data.title.attributes"
            html="data.title.html"></h3>

        <p attr="data.description.attributes"
           html="data.description.html"></p>

        <a href="
           <div attr='data.link.attributes'
            html='data.title.html'>
           </div>"
           >En savoir plus
        </a>
    </div>
</div>>
```

But it's not working for the link; what am i missing ?

Already tried also something like

`<a data-bind="attr: { href: data.link.attributes }">En savoir plus</a>`

Then i also have a media field to make an iframe for an image / video; but that's the next step